# In react, how to use draft-js to work with update/edit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using draft-js to render rich text editor inside my form. Can someone please help me figure out how can I show the value of the state on the Editor that is saved in my database?

This is what I have so far:

```
import { convertFromRaw, EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

class EditForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(this.props.description)))
    };
  }

  // componentWillMount() {
  //   this.setState({
  //     description: this.props.description
  //   });
  // }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      description: nextProps.description
    });
  }

  onDescriptionChange(event) {
    this.setState({ description: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { description } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Editor value={description} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditForm;
```

Comment: What's the content of "description" you are parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

you need convert your "variables" to `draftjs`'s [render model](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

The method [`createWithContent`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/#createwithcontent) needs a `ContentState` as a first argument.

Import `ContentState`:

```
import { ContentState } from "draft-js";
```

then, update your state like this:

```
this.state = {
  description:                     
    EditorState.createWithContent(
      ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(this.props.description)
      )
    )
};
```